# Is there an way to get source code from .idb file?

Tags: c++, c, src

So, I have an .IDB file and I want to ask if is there an way to get source code from .idb file? Thanks.

Comment: What is an IDB file? It would be good it you gave more context such as your development environment and where/how that file is generated.

Comment: "Intermediate file created by a Visual Studio program, such as Visual C++, during the debugging process; saves the compiler's state and is used for minimal program rebuilds and incremental compilations."

Comment: I actually knew. But was trying to prompt you to put some thought into writing a clear and understandable question. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71275377/edit) your post to update it with that rather important info.

Comment: What do you mean by important info?

Comment: The important info you have put into your first comment. You didn't tag Visual Studio  or Windows or make any mention of them. The tags you did use and the description do not clearly explain the context of your question.

Comment: Why do you need that. Where do you have the idb file from, if it is not from your own project where the source already exists?

Comment: The answer is most likely "no". What happened? Did you delete the source files by mistake?

Comment: yep. i most likely lost all of them. only this left

Comment: Too late, but this illustrates how capital it is to **always** have a source control system, even for small projects, and at least one remote repository that can serve as backup.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot easily restore deleted files and certainly not with .idb files. If you have no backup, you're out of luck.

There are tools which may help to undelete deleted files, but there is no guarantee.
Google "undelete files".

Comment: Thanks. I could not recover all files but I recovered a few.